# f2py does not allocate memory for an f77 array

Tags: python, arrays, memory, f2py

I am trying to wrap an old and somewhat messy f77 code with f2py. I get everything to compile with 2 different compilers (gfortran and ifort), nevertheless the code segfaults when executed from python, while the original f77 works. The reason seems to be unallocated memory for an array. To be more precise, in the main subroutine the variable are declared as follows:

```
  implicit double precision (a-h,o-z)
  include 'gmm01f.par.f'
  include 'ampld.par.f'
  parameter (nangmax=1801)
  parameter (nmp=np*(np+2),nmp0=(np+1)*(np+4)/2)
  parameter (ni0=np*(np+1)*(2*np+1)/3+np*np)
  parameter (ng0=np*(2*np**3+10*np**2+19*np+5)/6)
  parameter (nrc=4*np*(np+1)*(np+2)/3+np)
  integer u,v,u0,nmax(nLp),uvmax(nLp),ind(nLp),idshp(nLp)
  double precision k,r0(9,nLp),x(nLp),xc(nLp),r00(3,nLp),
 +   besj(0:2*np+1),besy(0:2*np+1),smue(4,4),i11(nangmax),
 +   i21(nangmax),i22(nangmax),i12(nangmax),inat(nangmax),
 +   pol(nangmax),dang(nangmax),
 +   cscaxi(nLp),cscayi(nLp),cextxi(nLp),cextyi(nLp),
 +   cabsxi(nLp),cabsyi(nLp),cexti(nLp),cabsi(nLp),cscai(nLp),
 +   assymi(nLp),assymxi(nLp),assymyi(nLp),cprxi(nLp),
 +   cpryi(nLp),cpri(nLp),drot(nrc),c0i(nLp),c1i(nLp)
  double precision  shp(3,nLp),
 &   RT11(NPN6,NPN4,NPN4),RT12(NPN6,NPN4,NPN4),
 &   RT21(NPN6,NPN4,NPN4),RT22(NPN6,NPN4,NPN4),
 &   IT11(NPN6,NPN4,NPN4),IT12(NPN6,NPN4,NPN4),
 &   IT21(NPN6,NPN4,NPN4),IT22(NPN6,NPN4,NPN4)
  complex*16 A,B,cmz,Aj,Bj,A2,B2,Aj2,Bj2,A0,B0,ci,cin,
 +   s2x,s4x,s3y,s1y,s2xj,s4xj,s3yj,s1yj,
 +   ref(nLp),refc(nLp),atr(2,np,nmp),at(nmp),bt(nmp),ek(np),
 +   p0(nLp,nmp),q0(nLp,nmp),an(np),bn(np),atj(nmp),btj(nmp),
 +   as00(nLp,nmp),bs00(nLp,nmp),as0(nLp,nmp),bs0(nLp,nmp),
 +   as(nLp,nmp),bs(nLp,nmp),asc(nLp,nmp),bsc(nLp,nmp),
 +   as1(nLp,nmp),bs1(nLp,nmp),ast(nLp,nmp),bst(nLp,nmp),
 +   asp(nLp,nmp),bsp(nLp,nmp),asv(nLp,nmp),bsv(nLp,nmp),
 +   asx(nLp,nmp),bsx(nLp,nmp),aty(nmp),bty(nmp),atyj(nmp),
 +   btyj(nmp),Ay(2),By(2),Ayj(2),Byj(2),
 +   tbar(nLp,2,2,nmp,nmp),tbar0(2,2,nmp,nmp),bar(2,2),
 +   ekt(-2*np:2*np)
  CHARACTER FLNAME*20,fileout*20,fileout1*19,flout*22
  COMMON/MIESUB/ twopi,pih
  common/rot/bcof(0:np+2),dc(-np:np,0:nmp)
  common/fnr/fnr(0:2*(np+2))
  common/pitau/pi(nmp0),tau(nmp0)
  common/tran/atr
  common/ig0/iga0(ni0)
  common/g0/ga0(ng0)
  common/cofmnv0/cof0(ni0)
  common/crot/cofsr(nmp)
  COMMON /TMAT/ RT11,RT12,RT21,RT22,IT11,IT12,IT21,IT22
```

where **gmm01f.par.f** is as follows:

```
      parameter (nLp=10,np=30)
```

and **ampld.par.f** is:

```
  Parameter (NPN1=100, NPNG1=500, NPNG2=2*NPNG1, NPN2=2*NPN1,
 &           NPL=NPN2+1, NPN3=NPN1+1,
 &           NPN4=NPN1, NPN5=2*NPN4, NPN6=NPN4+1)
```

What happens is that the memory for the **cofsr(nmp)** array seems, for some reason, not to be allocated, and anytime I try to assign a value to the array the program segfaults. This only happens for **cofsr(nmp)** and not for the other arrays, that are initialized to 0 at the beginning of the program. I can't really see any reason for this behavior, the only exception being the fact that in a subroutine **cofsr(nmp)** is initialized as

```
  subroutine cofsrd(nmax)
  include 'gmm01f.par.f'
  parameter (nmp=np*(np+2))
  double precision cofsr(nmp),lnfacd,c
  common/crot/cofsr
```

while otherwise we only have the

```
implicit double precision (a-h,o-z)
```

statement.

As additional informations the beginning of the subroutine is the following:

```
  SUBROUTINE gmm03f(idMie,
 &                  idAlpha,idBeta,iseed,
 &                  small,MXINT,
 &                  NADD,
 &                  fint,
 &                  sang,pang,
 &                  w,irat,
 &                  nL,
 &                  idshp,shp,r0,
 &                  cextxi,cextyi,cscaxi,
 &                  cscayi,cabsxi,cabsyi)

Cf2py intent(in) idMie
Cf2py intent(in) idAlpha,idBeta,iseed
Cf2py intent(in) small,MXINT
Cf2py intent(in) NADD
Cf2py intent(in) fint
Cf2py intent(in) sang,pang
Cf2py intent(in) w,irat
Cf2py intent(in) nL
Cf2py intent(in) idshp,shp,r0
Cf2py intent(out) cextxi,cextyi,cscaxi,cscayi,cabsxi,cabsyi
```

and the signature file is:

```
python module stm ! in
 interface  ! in :stm
    subroutine  gmm03f(idmie,idalpha,idbeta,iseed,small,mxint,nadd,fint,sang,pang,w,irat,nl,idshp,shp,r0,cextxi,cextyi,cscaxi,cscayi,cabsxi,cabsyi) ! in :stm:stm.f
        integer intent(in) :: idmie
        integer intent(in) :: idalpha
        integer intent(in) :: idbeta
        integer intent(in) :: iseed
        double precision intent(in) :: small
        integer intent(in) :: mxint
        integer intent(in) :: nadd
        double precision intent(in) :: fint
        double precision intent(in) :: sang
        double precision intent(in) :: pang
        double precision intent(in) :: w
        integer intent(in) :: irat
        integer intent(in) :: nl
        integer dimension(10),intent(in) :: idshp
        double precision dimension(3,10),intent(in) :: shp
        double precision dimension(9,10),intent(in) :: r0
        double precision dimension(10),intent(out) :: cextxi
        double precision dimension(10),intent(out) :: cextyi
        double precision dimension(10),intent(out) :: cscaxi
        double precision dimension(10),intent(out) :: cscayi
        double precision dimension(10),intent(out) :: cabsxi
        double precision dimension(10),intent(out) :: cabsyi
        double precision dimension(527) :: pi
        double precision dimension(527) :: tau
        double precision dimension(65) :: fnr
        double precision dimension(101,100,100) :: rt11
        double precision dimension(101,100,100) :: rt12
        double precision dimension(101,100,100) :: rt21
        double precision dimension(101,100,100) :: rt22
        double precision dimension(101,100,100) :: it11
        double precision dimension(101,100,100) :: it12
        double precision dimension(101,100,100) :: it21
        double precision dimension(101,100,100) :: it22
        integer dimension(19810) :: iga0
        double precision :: twopi
        double precision :: pih
        double precision dimension(960) :: cofsr
        complex*16 dimension(2,30,960) :: atr
        double precision dimension(19810) :: cof0
        double precision dimension(317875) :: ga0
        double precision dimension(33) :: bcof
        double precision dimension(np + 31,961) :: dc
        common /pitau/ pi,tau
        common /fnr/ fnr
        common /tmat/ rt11,rt12,rt21,rt22,it11,it12,it21,it22
        common /ig0/ iga0
        common /miesub/ twopi,pih
        common /crot/ cofsr
        common /tran/ atr
        common /cofmnv0/ cof0
        common /g0/ ga0
        common /rot/ bcof,dc
        include 'gmm01f.par.f'
        include 'ampld.par.f'
    end subroutine gmm03f
  end interface
end python module stm
```

Thanks a Lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer, even if I can't really say that I understand the rationale behind it. What causes the problem is the name of the common block:

```
 common/crot/cofsr(nmp)
```

when switched with a different name such as

```
 common/testok/cofsr(nmp)
```

everything works as expected, therefore my problem is solved.